# LLVM asserts "Resolving symbol outside this responsibility set"

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

Why does my call to

```
jit->lookup("test");
```

hit a failed assert: "Resolving symbol outside this responsibility set"?

It does this when I create my function as:

```
define double @test() {
begin:
  ret double 1.343000e+01
}
```

But it works fine (i.e., finds it without an assert) when I create the function as

```
define void @test() {
begin:
  ret void
}
```

It is not a case of not finding the function "test", it has different behavior if I lookup a name that doesn't exist.

Here's the code that hits the assert:

```
ThreadSafeModule Create_M()
{
    auto pCtx = make_unique<LLVMContext>();
    LLVMContext& ctx = *pCtx;
    auto pM = make_unique<Module>("myModule", ctx);
    Module& M = *pM;

    IRBuilder<> builder(ctx);

    FunctionType* FT = FunctionType::get(Type::getDoubleTy(ctx),false);
    Function* testFn = Function::Create(FT, 
                GlobalValue::LinkageTypes::ExternalLinkage, "test", M);
    auto BB = BasicBlock::Create(ctx,"begin",testFn);
    builder.SetInsertPoint(BB);
    builder.CreateRet(ConstantFP::get(ctx,APFloat(13.43)));

    outs() << M;        // For debugging

    return ThreadSafeModule(std::move(pM), std::move(pCtx));
}


int main()
{
    InitializeNativeTarget();
    InitializeNativeTargetAsmPrinter();

    // Create an LLJIT instance.
    auto jit = ExitOnErr(LLJITBuilder().create());
    auto M1 = Create_M();
    ExitOnErr(jit->addIRModule(std::move(M1)));
    auto testSym = ExitOnErr(jit->lookup("test"));
}
```

Replace the function creation with these lines and it doesn't have the problem:

```
FunctionType* FT = FunctionType::get(Type::getVoidTy(ctx),false);
Function* testFn = Function::Create(FT, 
            GlobalValue::LinkageTypes::ExternalLinkage, "test", M);
auto BB = BasicBlock::Create(ctx,"begin",testFn);
builder.SetInsertPoint(BB);
builder.CreateRetVoid();
```

I'd like to understand what the assert means, why it asserts in the one case and not the other, and what I need to do for the (*double)() case to get it to work. I did a lot of searching for documentation on LLVM responsibility sets, and found almost nothing. Some mention at https://llvm.org/docs/ORCv2.html, but not enough for me to interpret what it is telling me with this assert.

I'm using the SVN repository version of LLVM as of 20-Aug-2019, building on Visual Studio 2017 15.9.6.

Comment: I discovered this natvis that makes it much easier to debug within LLVM:

https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/utils/LLVMVisualizers/llvm.natvis

Comment: I have figured out the symbol causing the assertion is not "test", but rather "__real@402e99999999999a", which apparently corresponds to the constant 13.5 that appears in the body. 

Here's what I see happening in the bowels or LLVM. doMaterialize() sets up a MaterializationUnit using the ES, which has 1 JD containing only 1 symbol, 'test'. This triggers the ObjectLayer to emit(). During this, onObjLoad calls notifyResolved() on the MU with 2 symbols, "test" AND "_real@....". But the MU doesn't know about "_real@" and asserts.

LLVM bug? I don't know how it is supposed to work.

Comment: I have run into the same issue. I found also that ints work as expected, but a double fails as you noted. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

To fix this error, add `ObjectLinkingLayer.setAutoClaimResponsibilityForObjectSymbols(true);`

Such as:

```cpp
auto jit = ExitOnErr(LLJITBuilder()
  .setJITTargetMachineBuilder(std::move(JTMB))
  .setObjectLinkingLayerCreator([&](ExecutionSession &ES, const Triple &TT) {
    auto ll = make_unique<ObjectLinkingLayer>(ES, 
        make_unique<jitlink::InProcessMemoryManager>());
    ll->setAutoClaimResponsibilityForObjectSymbols(true);
    return move(ll);
  })
  .create());
```

Answer (score 0):

This was indeed bug in ORC LLJIT on Windows platform.

See bug record here:
https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44337

Fix commit reference:
https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/84217ad66115cc31b184374a03c8333e4578996f

For anyone building **custom JIT / compiler-layer stack** by hand (not using LLJIT), all you need to do is force weak symbol autoclaim when emitting ELF images.

```
if (JTMB.getTargetTriple().isOSBinFormatCOFF())
{
    ObjectLayer.setAutoClaimResponsibilityForObjectSymbols(true);
}
```

http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1orc_1_1ObjectLinkingLayer.html#aa30bc825696d7254aef0fe76015d10ff

> If set, this ObjectLinkingLayer instance will claim responsibility for
>   any symbols provided by a given object file that were not already in
>   the MaterializationResponsibility instance.
>
> Setting this flag allows higher-level program representations (e.g.
>   LLVM IR) to be added based on only a subset of the symbols they
>   provide, without having to write intervening layers to scan and add
>   the additional symbols. This trades diagnostic quality for convenience
>   however: If all symbols are enumerated up-front then clashes can be
>   detected and reported early (and usually deterministically). If this
>   option is set, clashes for the additional symbols may not be detected
>   until late, and detection may depend on the flow of control through
>   JIT'd code. Use with care.